# Instantiating an Excel Table

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have an Excel Table which I want to use as a source for other tasks. It contains a list of names and ids in my case, and some other data. This table is slowly growing and everything is there to stay. What I would love to have is being able to instantiate this object in different workbooks. I can use VBA, but I'm more than hesitant to start diving into that these days. Any ideas for a more elegant alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by instantiate you just mean you want the table to be linked in an external workbook then that is easy using the native data tools in Excel.

1. Click Data
2. Get Data
3. From File
4. From Workbook
5. Select the source workbook with the table

This brings up the data import interface. From here you can see all the objects in the workbook. Select the table object you want to import. Click Load.

This is now a connected query. You can press `Data > Refresh All` and it will pull the latest data from the table. In this way the tables are linked. You would need to refresh your copy before doing anywork in the new workbook.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is call a linked reference.

- [MS: External Reference Link](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-an-external-reference-link-to-a-cell-range-in-another-workbook-c98d1803-dd75-4668-ac6a-d7cca2a9b95f)

Two methods for using a linked reference (examples are Table centric):

1. Manually type in the linked reference:

   - `'workbook file name.xlsx'!Table_Name[#All]`
   - The single quotes are needed if the filename contains spaces or special characters.
   - More [Table Operators](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/using-structured-references-with-excel-tables-f5ed2452-2337-4f71-bed3-c8ae6d2b276e#tblID0EAAHAAA) from *MS: Using Structured References with Excel Tables* page.
2. Select the Source Range:

   - Open the source workbook (before creating the formula that will reference it).
   - Create the formula and at the point where the linked reference is needed,
   - On the View tab, in the Window group, click Switch Windows.
   - Select the source workbook and navigate to the sheet tab.
   - Select the reference range cell(s).
   - return to completing the formula.

To view the entire Table:

- Where the instance of the table is needed,
- Select a range of cells large enough to contain the table.

  - If the table may grow, add extra columns and/or rows to allow for this growth.
  - Add `IFERROR(<formula>,"")` to hide `#N/A`.
  - Add an additional guard to indicate if the source table has outgrown the allotted space.
- In the formula bar, enter `='Table Workbook Name.xlsx'!Table_Name[#All]` or enter `=` and then use method 1 above and select the entire table.
- This is CSE formula so use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Enter</kbd>